# sim800 and Codeigniter CSRF token problem

Tags: php, codeigniter, csrf, at-command, sim800

hi Sorry for my weak English. I'm trying to receive the JSON data from Sim800 on my Server using Codeigniter. when in config.php file i set the `$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;` the Server Response 403 error and when it's `false` Server Response 200 and everything is OK.what can i do for this problem? for now in config.php i add this: `$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array('customer/query');`,Is there another way?

---

in my client side Sim800 module I'm using this commands.

```
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"CONTYPE","GPRS"
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","mtnirancell"
AT+SAPBR=1,1
AT+SAPBR=2,1
AT+HTTPINIT
AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","http://www.mysiteaddress.ir/customer/query"
AT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","application/json"
AT+HTTPDATA=20,10000 //data is 20 Bytes,maximum latency time is 10000 ms.
// Wait a few moments to Receive "DOWNLOAD" from sim800c module
{"data":"my sensor value"} // The data I want to send

AT+HTTPACTION=1 // send data with POST method
```

after this commands module response

```
OK

+HTTPACTION: 1,403,86 // 403 error
```

and for PHP server I'm using this codes:

```
$request_body="";
$request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$record = urldecode($request_body);
$record = json_decode($request_body,true);
```